# TS playwright. Unable to re-use authentication when using POM

Tags: typescript, authentication, automation, playwright, pageobjects

Im new to Playwright, but I know that we can re-use the authencation with Playwright. However, when I approach the test with POM, it seems like I could not use it. Could anyone able to help me with this matter?

I was able to generate the storageState.json file where it contains all the info login in the setup. However, when It comes to the test, It ask me to re-login again.

```
I have my logInPageAction.ts 

import {expect, Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { LoginPageLocator } from '../pageLocator/loginPage';
import  { BasePageAction } from './BasePage';


export class logInPageAction extends BasePageAction {
    constructor(public page: Page ) { 
        super(page)
    }

    async goToPage(url: string){
        await this.page.goto(`${url}`,{ timeout: 45000 });
    }

    async validLogin(username:string , password:string){
        await this.page.click(LoginPageLocator.aggreeToAllBnt);
        await this.page.click(LoginPageLocator.logInNowBnt);
        await this.page.fill(LoginPageLocator.idpUsernameInput,username);
        await this.page.click(LoginPageLocator.idpNextBnt);
        await this.page.fill(LoginPageLocator.passwordInput,password);
        await this.page.click(LoginPageLocator.signInBnt);

        // await expect(this.page).toHaveURL('/myproducts/')
    }
```

```
globle-setup.ts
import { chromium, expect, FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { logInPageAction } from '../PageAction/logInPageAction';
import { creatdential } from '../config/config';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) { 

  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext()
  const page = await context.newPage()

  const newLoginPage = new logInPageAction(page)
  const creaden = new creatdential()
  const baseURL =  await creaden.getBaseUrl()
  await console.log (baseURL)
  await newLoginPage.goToPage(`${baseURL}/app`)
  await newLoginPage.validLogin(await creaden.getUserName(),await creaden.getPassword())

  await page.context().storageState({ path:'storageState.json' });

  global.__BROWSER__ = browser;
  global.__CONTEXT__ = context;
  global.__PAGE__ = page;
}
export default globalSetup;
```

```
playwright.config.ts

import { PlaywrightTestConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {

  testDir: './tests',
  timeout: 240 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 45000
  },
  /* Global setup */
  reporter: 'html',
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./support/global-setup'),

  use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    storageState: './storageState.json',
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',

      /* Project-specific settings. */
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
        headless: false

      },
    },
  ],
};
export default config;
```

```
test file example.spec.ts

import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

import { logInPageAction } from '../PageAction/logInPageAction';
import { BasePageAction } from '../PageAction/BasePage';

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {

  const pag = new BasePageAction(page)
  await pag.gotoMainPage(await pag.getBaseUrl())
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Demo/);
});
```

Comment: What's the exact problem/question here? [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) can offer guidance on how to ask a concrete, specific question.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { chromium } from '@playwright/test';
import { logInPageAction } from '../PageAction/logInPageAction';
import { Credential } from '../config/config'; // Assuming creatdential is a typo.

async function globalSetup() { 
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  const loginPage = new logInPageAction(page);
  const credential = new Credential(); // Assuming Credential is a class that provides login details.
  const baseURL = await credential.getBaseUrl();
  
  await loginPage.goToPage(`${baseURL}/app`);
  await loginPage.validLogin(await credential.getUserName(), await credential.getPassword());

  // Save the authentication state.
  await context.storageState({ path: 'storageState.json' });

  await browser.close(); // Make sure to close the browser after setup to avoid any open sessions.
}

export default globalSetup;
```

Comment: Hi @Hakeo Hiratani it gave me the same issus. It still asks me to login again
I tried without POM  and it works well
Does Playwright have anything like driver cache similar with selenium ?

Comment: The test file you've shown is very basic and doesn't seem to interact with the login state directly. Ensure that any test that requires a logged-in state does not try to log in again but rather relies on the storageState.json for authentication.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: './tests',
  timeout: 240 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 45000
  },
  reporter: 'html',
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./support/global-setup'), // Ensure this path is correct.
  use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    storageState: './storageState.json', // Correct relative path to your project structure.
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
        headless: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};

export default config;
```